# Using inline import in Express use

Tags: node.js, express, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I am switching my project to ES6 and have been replacing all inline `require` with `import`.
Replacing the top level `require` was no issue but when I try to replace the inline `require`, I get `TypeError: app.use() requires a middleware function`

```
// We need these modules to be present.
import path from "path";
import dotEnv from "dotenv";
import express from "express";
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
import connectToDatabase from "./database.js";
import morganMiddleware from "./middlewares/morgan.middleware.js";

// Initialise exress
const app = express();

// Initialise dotEnv;
dotEnv.config();

// Define file and directory path
const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);

// Load environment variables
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 1313;

// Properly parse the json and urlencoed data
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.json());

// Add the morgan middleware
app.use(morganMiddleware);

// When we respond with a json object, indent every block with 4 spaces.
app.set("json spaces", 4);

// Where should we look for the static files
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../public")));

//Load the different routes
app.use(import("./controllers/index.js"));

// Connect to database
connectToDatabase();

// Custom Error handling
app.use((req, res) => {
   res.status(404).json({
      type: "error",
      message: "404: Page not Found"});
});

app.use((error, req, res, next) => {
   res.status(500).json({
      type: "error",
      message: "500: Internal Server Error"});
});

// Start the server
app.listen(PORT, () => {
   console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

Does anyone know what's going here?

This is what in the `controllers/index.js` file

```
// Loading the modules
import { Router } from "express";

const router = Router()

// Load the models
import ProjectsData, { addProject } from "../models/projects.js";

router.post("/", (req, res) => {
    res.send("Cool. We are working. Now you can proceed to cry.");
});

export default router;
```

Comment: you should import the file earlier, and just use it `.use`, not write `import` in use. Thats mostly it

Comment: This works but is there no way to do inline/dynamic imports.

Comment: You *did* an inline/dynamic `import()`, but it doesn't work because it returns a promise and not the router. You just shouldn't use one here. Write declarative code instead.

Comment: I know I was just asking if there was a way to make inline work. But thanks. I did not know that import returns a promise.

Comment: There is a way but you're not going to like it: `import().then(x => app.use(x))`

Comment: Or use `async/await`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, move the import up to the others since you're importing it every time anyway.

`import indexController from "./controllers/index.js"`

`app.use(indexController)`

But if you really need to import something inline, here's the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import). But i'll give you an example.

All inline imports returns promises and needs to be awaited.
Also, when you're writing just `import('...')` it expects a default export, which you don't have in that specific file. So here's how you'd solve your problem.

`app.use((await import("./controllers/index.js")).default)`

Comment: Thank you! I think the best way is to move it up and handle it that way.

Comment: Just one thing, I have a default export in that file. `export default router;`

Comment: Dynamic import is still useful if the import path is a variable (not a string literal). In my projects I often scan for modules (usually controllers) in a directory and mount them to express paths dynamically: `for (const c of controllers) { app.use((await import(c)).route) }`. This way I get the best thing about path based routing (not needing to maintain a separate routing file) and avoid the worst part about path based routing (mangling directory and file names)

Comment: you could be using `require` for that, but not import (and with some settings you can use both in one file - exactly for dynamic imports. Just remember they are not very secure and should really be avoided